# Ubuntu 14.04 trying to mount non existent hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and it sticks on boot up because it is trying to mount `mnt/5dae46e774ac431f`.  This drive does not exist on my system (it did once but now it has been replaced).

*What must I do to tell Ubuntu not to look for the non existent drive?*

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to a terminal  by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. type:

   `sudo apt-get install gksudo`

   `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`
3. put a `#` in front of the line that has `mnt/5dae46e774ac431f` in it
4. type `sudo mount -a`
5. If you get no errors, you will not get any at the next reboot neither.